# HTML elements built with jQuery are different in Chrome

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor to insert markups for citations (footnotes). I have written a CKEditor plugin that allows the user to click a button in a CKEditor instance and enter a new citation or select an existing one. The markup is built using jQuery:

```
    // see http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-idioms.html#footnotes
    var $cite = $("<sup>").append($("<a>").attr("href", "#").attr("data-citationid", citationId).html("[" + citationId + "]"));
    editor.insertHtml($cite.get(0).outerHTML);
```

where `data-citationid` references the citation's id in the database. The problem is that the inserted markup is different in Chrome (23.0.1271.97 m).

Firefox (17.0.1) and IE (9.0.8112.16421) insert the desired

```
<sup><a data-citationid="26" href="#">[26]</a></sup>
```

but Chrome strips the `<sup>` tags and inserts

```
<a data-citationid="26" href="#" style="vertical-align: super;">[26]</a>
```

My questions are:

- Can I build the markup so that it will always be rendered as desired?
- Is the browser or CKEditor changing the markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`insertHTML` should not be used for inserting HTML due to browser inconsistencies. The [correct way](http://ckeditor.com/comment/56377#comment-56377) to insert HTML is to create an element and call `insertElement`.

This is working for me:

```
    var cite = "<sup><a href=\"#\" data-citationid=\"" + citationId + "\">[" + citationId + "]</a></sup>";
    var element = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml(cite, editorInstance.document);
    editorInstance.insertElement(element);
```

Answer (score 1):

The .outerHTML is native JS instead of jquery and it's implementation can vary. Try wrapping it and calling `.html()` on the wrapper like this

```
$cite.clone().wrap('<div>').parent().html();
```

Comment: This works for the first one I insert but subsequent inserts revert to setting the style. I'm hitting the same code every time so I don't know what's going on with this. I'm seeing the same behavior even when I hand code the html. The problem must lie with ckeditor.